# Fix a Copy Function to Include Title/Merged Cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have a copy function that works except that it does not work when copying through a worksheet with title/header information that includes merged cells. Is there any way to tell VBA to start looking after row 5 (so data starts at row 6)

Here is the code:

```
Sub FillAtoF()
For Each Area In Columns("A:F").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    If Area.Cells.Row <= ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count Then
        Area.Cells = Range(Area.Address).Offset(-1, 0).Value
    End If
Next Area
```

The worksheet has merged cells that occupy row 1-5 and columns A-F

Please advise! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will set your range to begin at row 6 and end at the end of data in column A

```
Sub FillAtoF()
Dim lastrow As Integer
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range(Cells(6, "A"), Cells(lastrow, "F"))

For Each c In rng 
    'if stuff
Next

End Sub
```

I'm not sure what your `if` is doing, but you can do it with a `for` loop within the range. Or go row by row. Or area by area.

I guess what you have would be this -

```
Sub FillAtoF()
Dim lastrow As Integer
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range(Cells(6, "A"), Cells(lastrow, "F"))

For Each Area In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
         Area.Cells = Range(Area.Address).Offset(-1, 0).Value
Next Area

End Sub
```